Real Valued Polynomials and Inner Product
Let $P_n$ denote the space of real-valued polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$. For which values of $n$ does
$$
\langle f, g\rangle = f(1)g(1) + f(2)g(2) + f(3)g(3)
$$
define an inner product on $P_n$?
I understand that an inner product on a vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ is a function $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following properties:

Linearity in the first argument: $$\langleα_1x_1 + α_2x_2, y\rangle = α_1\langle x_1, y\rangle + α_2\langle x_2, y\rangle, α_1, α_2 ∈ \mathbb{R}, x_1,x_2,y ∈ V $$

Symmetry: $$\langle x, y \rangle=\overline{\langle y, x \rangle}, x,y ∈ V$$

Positive-definiteness: $$\langle x, x\rangle ≥ 0 ; \langle x, x\rangle =0 <=>x=0,x ∈V $$


$\langle f, g\rangle$ is symmetric because polynomials commute. For symmetry, we have
$$\langle  f, f\rangle = f(1)^2+f(2)^3+f(3)^2,$$
which is has roots when $f(1)=0,f(2)=2,f(3)=0$. For a polynomial to have $n$ distinct roots, it must be of degree at least 2. So, $n≥2$? Also, I am fairly certain $\langle f, g\rangle$ is linear in its first argument, but I am not quite sure how to show this. Is my conclusion $n≥2$ correct?

"For a polynomial to have n distinct roots,it must be of degree atleast 2",from where you got this result?

Oops, it should be "for a polynomial to have n distinct roots, it must be of degree at least n." This is a result of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, which states "you will have n roots for a polynomial of nth degree." Is it wrong to claim, if a polynomial has n roots, it will be of nth degree?
